# Changing trains

Tags: internal-consistency

What are some possible solutions/tools that an acrobatic person could use to jump/transfer from one train/truck to another both going 500 km/hr in the opposite direction?

Comment: Do you want the person to survive or is it ok if some part of the body makes the jump?

Comment: I voted to put it on hold as a story set in a world instead of world building. If you have a worldbuilding goal here, please edit and elaborate. By the way, questions that are 1—3 sentences long attract downvotes. It's good to show you already put some thoughts into it.

Comment: If you are going that fast, the first thing would be air friction, I'm not sure you could even have a person standing up at that kind of speed without heavy protection

Comment: obviously the police force ;P

Comment: Internet is full of stupid people trying to get down a moving car and learning physics the hard way. And they didn't get a delta v of 277 m/s.

Comment: @Raditz_35, the wording doesn't seem to require survival, only transfer

Comment: Essentially the same equipment as you'd need to get from one jet to another going in opposite directions in mid air : your prayer beads and a miracle.

Comment: Assuming extremely long trains, with perfectly smooth roofs, travelling on parallel tracks for at least 20 seconds, you'll need a ladder and a lot of good luck. Twenty seconds at effectively 1000km/h requires two 5.5 km long trains. I really wouldn't want to think about road vehicles travelling at 500 kph.

Answer (score 3):

They need the power of money.

Hop off at the next station and buy a ticket for the other train and hop on when it pulls back up

Anything other than that is going to end badly. You have a difference in speed of 1000 km per hour which is almost mach 1.

The person would be better off getting off the first train completely and then getting the second train so they change is only 500km per hour

The G-forces, friction and timing would kill anyone that tried, not to mention trying to avoid power lines, overhead bridges, tunnels etc.

Fighter pilots can take up to 9G wearing special suits which means it would take around two and a seconds at 9G to get from 500kph to 500kph the other way in which the distance needed to be traveled is almost 700 metres.

Now considered you don't want to be doing 9G when you reach the second train, you're going to want to slow down which means that distance is going to be much longer.

There really isn't a way to just jump from train to train and not splatter yourself.

Answer (score 2):

Some time before the trains pass each other use a parafoil type parachute to launch off the first train, trading velocity for altitude, then use some kind of grappling hook & bungee cord to attach yourself to the front of the second train as it goes by. Once attached quickly position yourself over the train and detach your parachute, ideally at an altitude that won't cause grievous harm. If the train's long enough you'll be able to land on it without dying from acceleration, then you'll want to use a quick release on that bungee cord so it doesn't catapult you onto the tracks ahead of the train.

The techniques you'll be using are called: Preparation, Equipment and Luck.

Comment: Do you have anything (math, a reference ...) so that one judge if they should believe you and this might actually work at those velocities?

Comment: @Raditz_35: It's obviously intended to work in *Hollywood* physics. The nature of Hollywood physics is that any sequence of events which can be described in a script is perfectly possible. This is well known.

Comment: @Raditz_35 Not without an agreed upon consultation rate and a signed waiver of liability, lol seriously though for something like this to work at those speeds and even be remotely safe/reliable so much engineering would be involved that the trains probably wouldn't resemble trains anymore. What I suggested was the absolute bare minimum theoretically possible way that said person could end up on the second train in a condition that would technically count as alive. I can refer you fighter pilot ejection seat and Fulton recovery systems but I'm not a military aviation engineer, so I don't know.